# Uncaught Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

To my understanding, react child elements must be inside a parent element. I have written like this. and showing uncaught invariant violation.

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <p>You {this.state.liked} this. Click to toggle.</p>
    <button onClick="this.increment">Increment</button>
  </div>
  );
 }
```

But when I am writing button on click event inside div its showing expected result.

```
render() {
  return (
   <div onClick={this.increment}>
    <p>You {this.state.liked} this. Click to toggle.</p>
   </div>
  );
}
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are passing a string in onClick props but React expects it to be a function.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i got it working on my end.

```
import { DOM } from "react";

return (
    DOM.div({
        className: "", onClick: () => {
            executeMicroflow(props.microflowProps);
        },
        style: { width: Value + "%" }
    })
);

function executeMicroflow(params) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had a TSX file in a folder with the same name.

I copied and pasted a file into a different location.  Because the folder existed.  There was no compile time error.

But at run time, the require call didn't map to a file.